# How to Fix Error Msg 41337, Level 16, State 100 in Create Memory Optimize table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to use a memory optimize table and  I got below error - how can I fix it? Any idea will be helpful.

> Msg 41337, Level 16, State 100, Line 1
>   Cannot create memory optimized tables. To create memory optimized tables, the database must have a MEMORY_OPTIMIZED_FILEGROUP that is online and has at least one container.

Code:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Account
(  
    AccountID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED
) WITH (MEMORY_OPTIMIZED=ON)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you must create a file Group first :

Create FileGroup :

> imoltp  is a sampledatabase

```
ALTER DATABASE imoltp ADD FILEGROUP imoltp_mod
    CONTAINS MEMORY_OPTIMIZED_DATA;
```

Add DatabaseFile To Your File Group :

```
ALTER DATABASE imoltp ADD FILE (
    name='imoltp_mod1', filename='c:\data\imoltp_mod1')
    TO FILEGROUP imoltp_mod;
```

Create Memory Optimize Table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Account(   
    AccountID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED
    ) WITH (MEMORY_OPTIMIZED=ON)
```

take a look at this for get more Info :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/creating-a-memory-optimized-table-and-a-natively-compiled-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-ver15
for more detail